# Part identification

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, power, usb, temperature-sensor

This may be a dumb question but i would like to know what this part is. Anyone who knows?[image]

Comment: Create a full picture (who knows what's behind your fingers), dimensions, any textual identification, where and in what device you found it (and what brand, model).

Comment: maybe something like that?
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32847035065.html

Comment: We cannot see anything on that image. About 99% of that image is not showing the part

Comment: Maybe something like this (just kidding): https://nl.123rf.com/photo_73468723_rustieke-houten-plank-met-nagels-geïsoleerde-bruine-plank-.html

Comment: it looks like an index finger and the middle finger ... the item taking up most of the image is a wall

Answer (score 3):

This looks like something out of an Arduino n-part “sensor kit”. It’s hard to tell because the quality of the image is not very good.

My guess is, this is an analog temperature sensor, like [in this link](https://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-37-in-1-Sensors-Kit-Explained/), part number 18. You can also find an example sketch there.